# Cannot assign "u'1'": "Vote.design" must be a "Design" instance

Tags: django

models:

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    design = models.ForeignKey(Design)
    vote = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2,decimal_places=1, choices=RATE_CHOICES)
```

views:

```
def add_vote(request, id, vote):
    user = request.user
    Vote.objects.create(user=user, design = id, vote = vote)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

urls:

```
url(r'^vote/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<vote>\d{1,5})/', 'app.views.add_vote'),
```

If I try for example:

**127.0.0.1:8000/vote/1/3**

I have this error:

> ValueError at /vote/1/3/
>
> Cannot assign "u'1'": "Vote.design" must be a "Design" instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Vote.design` must be a `Design` instance, not a number:

```
from django.http import Http404

def add_vote(request, id, vote):
    user = request.user
    try:
        design = Design.objects.get(pk=id)
    except Design.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

    Vote.objects.create(user=user, design=design, vote=vote)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Or with a shortcut:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def add_vote(request, id, vote):
    user = request.user
    design = get_object_or_404(Design, pk=id)
    Vote.objects.create(user=user, design=design, vote=vote)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Comment: +1 for [`get_object_or_404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404)

Answer (score 1):

Change `design` into `design_id`, it will fix your error

```
def add_vote(request, id, vote):
    user = request.user
    Vote.objects.create(user=user, design_id = id, vote = vote)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve an instance of your `Design` model and assign the `design` property of `Vote` to that:

```
def add_vote(request, id, vote):
    user = request.user
    design = Design.objects.get(id=id)
    Vote.objects.create(user=user, design=design, vote=vote)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```